# SQL Newbie Stuck on Manager Flag Field Logic

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my first month of being a Data Analyst, and I can't seem to find an answer that is specific enough to my problem here to help. I am having trouble getting this manager flag field to work and I think I'm getting confused by the joins.

The goal is to match the EMPLIDs of JOB_VW A to see if they exist in the Supervisor_ID column of Supervisor_VW K. Supervisor_VW K has ALL employees in the company (including supervisors) in the K.EMPLID column. Someone can be in both the supervisor ID column and EMPL column at the same time, but in different rows. The SUP ID is the EMPL ID of someone in a manager position.

For example:
**Supervisor_VW K**

```
EMPL ID EMPL NAME      SUP ID  SUP NAME 
1       Smith, John    2       William, Mark 
5       Jarvis, John   2       William, Mark 
2       William, Mark  4       Rover, Spot
```

The results I am getting are as such
**QUERY RESULTS**

```
EMPLID EMPL NAME     MANAGER FLAG
2      William, Mark Y
2      William, Mark Y
4      Rover, Spot   Y
1      Smith, John   N
5      Jarvis, John  N
```

My current code is as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN K.Supervisor_Id IS NULL THEN 
  'N'
ELSE 
    'Y'
    END AS "ManagerFlag".....

FROM (SELECT K.*
FROM SUPERVISOR_VW K, JOB_VW A
WHERE K.SUPERVISOR_ID (+) = A.EMPLID
AND EXISTS (SELECT K1.EMPLID, K1.SUPERVISOR_ID
                     FROM SUPERVISOR_VW K1
              WHERE K1.EMPLID IN K1.Supervisor_Id)
                            ) K
```

So it seems that I am getting duplicate supervisor rows for every single employee that they supervise. If they supervise only one person, I get a singular row. If they supervise 20, I get 20 duplicate rows of that supervisor. HOWEVER, their employee that they supervise shows up in the table without issue and is properly labeled as N, no duplicates.

If anyone could help, please do! I appreciate you reading through my work, let me know if more info is required.

Comment: if you want to exclude duplicates, just do  ....select distinct K.*

Comment: @cableload - I tried that several times, doesn't work to solve the duplicates, which is why I think I am joining something wrong (or not joining something that needs to be joined).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to achieve the desired result is like this:

```
select emplid, emplname, 
   case when emplid in (select supid from supervisor_vw) then 'Y' 
                                                         else 'N' end as managerflag
from supervisor_vw;
```

Comment: Seems both my way and your way accomplish the same results, duplicates and all. Yours is clearly a lot more to the point though!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read through your entire query. You lost me at `A.EFFDT = ...` - what's the effective date of anything got to do with your question?

Comment: It doesn't, I was just putting that in there since it's in my main code to see if it did anything at all. I should have taken it out for the question - I will edit it.